# show dictionary angular component

Tags: angular

I have this Json:

```
{
    "BTC_BCN": {
        "id": 7,
        "last": "0.00000021",
        "lowestAsk": "0.00000021",
        "highestBid": "0.00000020",
        "percentChange": "0.05000000",
        "baseVolume": "11.09583267",
        "quoteVolume": "55302150.21663477",
        "isFrozen": "0",
        "high24hr": "0.00000021",
        "low24hr": "0.00000019"
    },
    "BTC_BTS": {
        "id": 14,
        "last": "0.00001507",
        "lowestAsk": "0.00001507",
        "highestBid": "0.00001505",
        "percentChange": "-0.00462351",
        "baseVolume": "16.45124387",
        "quoteVolume": "1091869.46387249",
        "isFrozen": "0",
        "high24hr": "0.00001525",
        "low24hr": "0.00001496"
    },
    "xxx_yyy": {
     },
    ........
}
```

This interface:

```
  export interface RootObject {
  marketName: paircoin;
}

export interface paircoin {
  id: number;
  last: string;
  lowestAsk: string;
  highestBid: string;
  percentChange: string;
  baseVolume: string;
  quoteVolume: string;
  isFrozen: string;
  high24hr: string;
  low24hr: string;
}
```

Html component:

```
<h1>Poloniex Coins</h1>

<p *ngIf="!(coinsPoloniex && coinsPoloniex.length)">
  There aren't coins to show you!!
</p>

<table class="table" *ngIf="coinsPoloniex && coinsPoloniex.length">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>MarketName</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>LowestAsk</th>
      <th>HighestBid</th>
      <th>PercentChange</th>
      <th>BaseVolume</th>
      <th>QuoteVolume</th>
      <th>IsFrozen</th>
      <th>High24hr</th>
      <th>Low24hr</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let iterateCoinP of coinsPoloniex">
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.marketName}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.id}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.last}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.lowestAsk}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.highestBid}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.percentChange}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.baseVolume}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.quoteVolume}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.isFrozen}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.high24hr}}</td>
      <td>{{iterateCoinP.low24hr}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How i can to iterate this Json? When i execute my project the component shows this: There aren't coins to show you!! ("coinsPoloniex" arrives empty)

[image: Component result].

I'm learning Angular and there are many things that i don't understand. Please, somebody help me!!

Regards.

Comment: Hello Jhon! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you elaborate what you mean by "the component not load anything"? Secondly, please provide a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ (such as a StackBlitz or Plunker) so that we could reproduce your example?

Comment: Hi Edric. Thanks for reply. I changed my redaction. I tried to be more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the name you are using in the ngFor:

try replacing

```
<tr *ngFor="let iterateCoinP of coins-poloniex">
```

for:

```
<tr *ngFor="let iterateCoinP of coinsPoloniex">
```

check this example: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pwcrdbas5RV1LEvc?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: Hi s-garces. Thanks for reply. You comment shows me that i has a error (I've corrected it.). However, i still can't show the content of JSON. I think that i don't iterating it correctly. What's your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keyvalue pipe or Object.keys(). Because coinsPoloniex returns Object of Object.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(coinsPoloniex); let i=index;">
   <tr *ngFor="let fields of Object.keys(coinsPoloniex[key]; let j=index;">
      <td *ngIf="!j">{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{coinsPoloniex[key][fields]}}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container
```